# How to get last modified date of latest file from S3 with Boto Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

This is structure of my s3 bucket

```
Bucket 1
    Company A
       File A-02/01/20
       File A-01/01/20
       File B-02/01/20
       File B-01/01/20

    Company B
       File A-02/01/20
       File A-01/01/20
```

I am trying to go to Bucket 1 >> navigate to company A FOLDER and find the latest version of File A and print the modified date, I wanted to do repeat the same steps for File B and then Company B Folder/File A. I am new to S3 and Boto3 so still learning. This is what my code is so far

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

today = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')

objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket='Bucket 1',Prefix = 'Company A'+'/File')

for o in objects["Contents"]:
    if o["LastModified"] != today:
        print(o["Key"] +" "+ str(o["LastModified"]))
```

This prints out the following:

```
File A_2019-10-28.csv 2019-11-11 18:31:17+00:00 
File A_2020-01-14.csv 2020-01-14 21:17:46+00:00 
File A_2020-01-28.csv 2020-01-29 19:19:58+00:00
```

But all I want is check File A_2020-01-28.csv and print if !=today, the same with File B

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that "File A" will always have a date at the end, you could use the 'A' part in the Prefix search. One thing to keep in mind with S3 is that there is no such thing as *folders*. That is something you imply by using '/' in they key name. S3 just works on Buckets/Keys.

The *latest* version of that file would be the the version that has the newest `last_modified` field. One approach is to sort the object list (of "A" files) on that attribute:

```
import boto3
from operator import attrgetter

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
objs = s3.Bucket('Bucket 1').objects.filter(Prefix='Company A/File A')

# sort the objects based on 'obj.last_modified'
sorted_objs = sorted(objs, key=attrgetter('last_modified'))

# The latest version of the file (the last one in the list)
latest = sorted_objs.pop()
```

As an example: I created foo1.txt, foo2.txt, foo3.txt in order. Then foo10.txt, foo5.txt. foo5.txt is my latest "foo" file.

```
>>> b.upload_file('/var/tmp/foo.txt','foo10.txt')
>>> b.upload_file('/var/tmp/foo.txt','foo5.txt')
>>> [i.key for i in b.objects.all()]  ## no ordering
['foo.txt', 'foo10.txt', 'foo2.txt', 'foo3.txt', 'foo5.txt']
>>> f2 = sorted(b.objects.all(), key=attrgetter('last_modified'))
>>> f2
[s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='foobar', key='foo.txt'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='foobar', key='foo2.txt'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='foobar', key='foo3.txt'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='foobar', key='foo10.txt'), s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='foobar', key='foo5.txt')]
>>> f2.pop()
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='foobar', key='foo5.txt')
```

For more details on Python sorting see: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Comment: This does not work for me - it says "'S3' object has no attribute 'Bucket'"

Comment: @DrCord I've updated the code snippet, it was meant to be combined with the original poster's code.

Answer (score 2):

Almost there, however the `if` statement compares 2 different `datetime` objects which contain date AND time - the time will differ. If you are after the dates only then change the `if` to:

```py
    if o["LastModified"].date() != today.date():
```

Works on Python 3.6.9.